# MaximizeBox set to false not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with windows forms with c#. I've set a property maximizebox = false to my form. But when i click on form it is getting maximized. How can i prevent it?

Note: If i set my form border style is none it is not working. In the other cases it is working fine

Thanks in advance
nagu

Comment: In your note, do you mean that the form is not resizing to maximised when you click on it or that it is resizing to maximized if the border style is set to none?

Comment: it is getting resized when i set border style to none. If is set border style to 3d or some other it is not getting resized.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you set the maximize box to false does not mean that the form cannot be maximized. It just means that your form hides that particular button.

You can stil max a form by double-clicking the title area, or from within the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid people resizing you form, set MaximumSize and MinimumSize to the same values, like this:

```
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400);
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400);
```